# Reshape pandas dataframe using easier fonctions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataiku

How it would be possible in the easiest way to reshape this data ? I succeded coding a really long fonction but I was wondering wheather there's an easier way or not.

[Here there is the image of the dataframe sample I would like to reshape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWLNy.png)

And here is the dataframe sample:

```
L = range(0,12)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col_1': ['a', 'b', 'c','a', 'b', 'c','a', 'b', 'c','a', 'b', 'c'], 'Col_2': ['', '', '','', '', '','', '', '','', '', ''], 'Col_3': ['x', 'y', 'z','xx', 'yy', 'zz','xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz','x1', 'y2', 'z3']},index = L)
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work :

```
df.set_index(["Col_1",df.groupby("Col_1").cumcount()]).unstack().T.droplevel(1)
```

next time pls offer a minimal reproducible example for the community to help you out ^^

Comment: I have a problem with the droplevel function, does it work for any dataframe ?

Comment: what error do you get ? @AlanNuñez

Comment: This one : <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'droplevel'